# How do I configure WebLogic 10.3 Web App To Use SAML 2 SSO and Identity Provider?

Tags: weblogic, single-sign-on, saml, web-applications

I have several Web applications all running in WebLogic 10 and I want to authenticate the users using SSO and WebLogic's built-in SAML 2 SSO support.
I configured a SAML2IdentityAsserter on the security realm and created a Web SSO Identity Provider Partner that uses the meta-data from the identity provider that I set up earlier.  That all seemed to go fine.
I deployed a simple web app that I'm using for testing that is configured to use this realm.  However, when I try to log in to the web app, it doesn't seem to even try to use the identity provider.  I set the  to both BASIC and CLIENT-CERT but both acted as if the SAM2IdentityAsserter wasn't set up.  I played with changing the order of the asserters and tried removing the default asserter but none of this has made a difference.
Has anyone had any success doing this under WLS 10.3?

Comment: Late Follow-up:  We did get this to work, and in fact it worked pretty well and was easy once we learned how the service provider works.
The service provider in Weblogic must have the full path to the resources being protected for each app and doesn't protect by root context using wild cards.  The trick is to protect a login page (\myapp\pages\login.seam for example), and then use app security to protect everything else and have the app redirect to the login page when the user is not authenticated.  This way you don't have to list all of your protected resources.
HTH

Comment: Eric - I'm working on a similar problem but we haven't seemed to be able to break through with the solution.  We're trying to use OpenSSO as the IDP with a Service Provider site in WebLogic.  We've done all the configuration as prescribed but nothing seems to happen.  WLS to not challenge an incoming user to prompt them for credentials.  A request just goes straight to the application as if there were no security.

Do you have any configuration details that you could share?  Or perhaps the one thing that you did and it started working?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could have a look at [Implementing SAML2 SP-initiated use case with Weblogic 10.3.4. and ADFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468836/implementing-saml2-sp-initiated-use-case-with-weblogic-10-3-4-and-adfs)

Best regards,

Luis

ps: now, It seems that we have got the right configuration, we are able to sign in our SSO System but we get and error from our Idp. You need to set up the security in your app through your descriptors (web.xml and weblogic.xml). Take a look at the configuration of your weblogic app console: $WEBLOGIC_HOME/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml and $WEBLOGIC_HOME/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/webapp/WEB-INF/weblogic.xml)